# Angular momentum of a two body system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum

This question comes from the Kleppner and Kolenkow textbook.

A ring of mass M and radius R lies on its side on a frictionless table. It is pivoted to the table at its rim. A bug of mass m walks around the ring with speed *v*, starting at the pivot. What is the rotational velocity of the ring when the bug is (a) halfway around and (b) back at the pivot.

The answer key states that angular momentum for the system should be conserved but this doesn't make sense to me. Doesn't a gravitational force act on the bug that results in a net external torque about the pivot? Why is angular momentum conserved for this system? Thanks

Comment: please add a sketch of the setup. If the ring lies in a horizontal plane and rotates around a vertical axis, gravity is equilibrated by the reaction of the horizontal surface and thus no net external moment acts on the system

Comment: I surmise the intention of that exercise question is as follows: the plane of the ring is perpendicular to the direction of gravity. K&K introduce a bit of extra complexity by not making the center of the ring the axis of rotation (of the ring). Instead some form of axial bearing is secured to a point along the perimeter. The ring pivots around that point, with the plane of the ring maintained perpendicular to the direction of gravity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the action takes place in a horizontal plane, so you can ignore gravity.

Why is angular momentum conserved? Because there are no external torques.  The only place where an external horizontal force is applied to the ring-bug system is at the pivot, so as long as you consider angular momentum about that point, the force produces no torque and angular momentum doesn't change.